# Why is \r not working and justs skips previous letters

Tags: python, pycharm

the code:

```
# Carriage return
print("123456\rabcd")
```

and it's appearing in console just that

```
abcd
```

instead of

```
abcd56
```

Comment: Note that there is a PyCharm tag; no need to put it in the title. I also took some freedom in changing your title to a more normal English sentence, hopefully without altering the meaning.

Comment: This is a side effect of your IDE.  It works in a normal console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with PyCharm. You can actually work around this via checking `Edit Configurations -> Execution -> Emulate terminal in output console.` This will run your code on python console instead of Pycharm's.

There is an issue about this in [jetbrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33627) too which mentions the solution I have suggested too.